# Javascript parasitic constructor seems failed to add a function to object, why

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, creation

I get this example from internet, using parasitic constructor to build an object, including giving it an extra function:

```
function SpecialArray(){
    var values=new Array();
    values.push.apply(values, arguments);
    values.toPipedString=function(){
        return this.join("|");
    }
}

var colors=new SpecialArray("red", "blue", "green");
console.log(colors.toPipedString());
```

Well the code runs with an exception:

```
console.log(colors.toPipedString());
                   ^
TypeError: colors.toPipedString is not a function
```

But I think I've attached the function to the object. Why it says function is not there?

Thanks.

Comment: `values` is a local array in `SpecialArray`, `toPipedString` is a method of that array ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attaching toPipedString function to internal var.
Try this:

```
function SpecialArray() {
    var values=new Array();
    values.push.apply(values, arguments);
    this.toPipedString = function() {
        return values.join("|");
    }
}

var colors = new SpecialArray("red", "blue", "green");
console.log(colors.toPipedString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to call `toPipedArray` as a function of specialArray, it needs to be on the prototype of special array.

```
function SpecialArray(){
    this.values=new Array();
    this.values.push.apply(this.values, arguments);

}
SpecialArray.prototype.toPipedString = function(){
    return this.values.join("|");
}
var colors=new SpecialArray("red", "blue", "green");
console.log(colors.toPipedString());
```

Nosyara's approach works as well. Using `this.Myfunction` within the function/object puts `myFunction` on the prototype as well.